# Tsql script to fill holes on a time line

Tags: t-sql

Hi there 
Suppose I have this query result on a temp table:

```
Person | Week | Month | Kms

John   | 1    |  1    |  1
Mary   | 1    |  1    |  2
Bob    | 2    |  1    |  3
```

And I want to show 0 when there's no values, that is, filling the holes with 0 when there's no data for a person in a week
ex:

```
 Person | Week | Month | Kms

    John   | 1    |  1    |  1
    Mary   | 1    |  1    |  2
  **Bob    | 1    |  1    |  0**
  **John   | 1    |  1    |  0**
  **Mary   | 1    |  1    |  0**
    Bob    | 2    |  1    |  3
```

(being ** the lines I want to add indicating 0 kms for a week)

any idea?

tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-join with a numbers table or left join from a numbers table.

See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059380/filling-gaps-in-dates-returned-from-database-pure-sql-solution-possible/5059735#5059735) regarding date sequences.