# How to insert saturdays and sundays between two dates in a table using sql?

Tags: sql

Say starting date is 8/04/2010
ending date is 8/04/2011
I need the dates of saturdays and sundays to be inserted in a table...
Need Help

Comment: which rdbms? microsoft sql server, mysql, oracle ...

Answer (score 2):

Use an unambiguous date format, like '2010-08-04'. This sorts correctly as either date or text, and everybody knows it means 04-Aug, not 08-Apr.

I like to use a [calendar table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030546/how-to-get-the-count-of-current-month-sundays-in-psql) for queries like this.  This will select the dates.

```
select cal_date
from calendar
where cal_date between '2010-08-04' and '2011-08-04'
and (day_of_week = 'Sat' or day_of_week = 'Sun');
```

Something like this will insert them into a table.  (Depending on the table.)

```
insert into your_table_name
select cal_date
from calendar
where cal_date between '2010-08-04' and '2011-08-04'
and (day_of_week = 'Sat' or day_of_week = 'Sun');
```

Comment: Everyone knows it is 04-Aug, except for SQL Server, which will return 4 for this query: `set language british
select DATEPART(month,CONVERT(datetime,'2010-08-04'))`. The unambiguous date only format for converting to datetime doesn't include dashes between the components, e.g. `'20100804'`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: You're right. The format 'yyyy-mm-dd' is just the SQL standard.