# SQL 'Round' Up a Date to a Given Day of the week

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

My company groups all tasks into individual weeks that end on a Thursday.  Thus a task due on 3/20/19 would be grouped into the 3/21 week and tasks due on 3/22 group into the 3/28/19 week.

I'm looking to calculate this field (called duedate_Weekdue) based on an input duedate.

The following works but doesn't seem like the simplest way to do this.  Anyone have more elegant methods?

```
Select 
getdate() as duedate,
datepart(yy,getdate()) as duedate_yr,
datepart(ww,getdate()) as duedate_ww,
CASE
    When datename(dw,Dateadd(day,1,getdate()))='Thursday' Then Dateadd(day,1,getdate())
    When datename(dw,Dateadd(day,2,getdate()))='Thursday' Then Dateadd(day,2,getdate())
    When datename(dw,Dateadd(day,3,getdate()))='Thursday' Then Dateadd(day,3,getdate())
    When datename(dw,Dateadd(day,4,getdate()))='Thursday' Then Dateadd(day,4,getdate())
    When datename(dw,Dateadd(day,5,getdate()))='Thursday' Then Dateadd(day,5,getdate())
    When datename(dw,Dateadd(day,6,getdate()))='Thursday' Then Dateadd(day,6,getdate())
    When datename(dw,Dateadd(day,0,getdate()))='Thursday' Then Dateadd(day,0,getdate())
END as duedate_Weekdue;
```

Comment: I will suggest a date table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reduce that to one line of code that uses a little math, and some SQL Engine trivia.

The answers that depend on `DATEPART` return non-deterministic results, depending on the setting for `DATEFIRST`, which tells the SQL Engine what day of the week to treat as the *first* day of the week.

There's a way to do what you want without the risk of getting the wrong result based on a change to the `DATEFIRST` setting.

Inside SQL Server, day number 0 is January 1, 1900, which happens to have been a Monday. We've all used this little trick to strip the time off of `GETDATE()` by calculating the number of days since day 0 then adding that number to day 0 to get today's date at midnight:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()),0)
```

Similarly, day number 3 was January 4, 1900. That's relevant because that day was a Thursday. Applying a little math to the number of days, and relying on the [`DATEDIFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to drop fractions, which it does, this calculation will always return the next Thursday for you:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, 3, GETDATE())/7)*7 + 7,3);
```

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18926121/5790584) for the assist.

So your final query comes down to this:

```
Select 
getdate() as duedate,
datepart(yy,getdate()) as duedate_yr,
datepart(ww,getdate()) as duedate_ww,
DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, 3, GETDATE())/7)*7 + 7,3) as duedate_Weekdue;
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply.  This worked exceptionally well for my purposes.  Thank you for also pointing me to your source as well.

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

If the first day of the week is Sunday, by using the modulo operator `%`:

```
cast(dateadd(day, (13 - datepart(dw, getdate())) % 7, getdate()) as date)  as duedate_Weekdue
```

I also applied the casting of the result to `date`.

Comment: this answer is dependent upon the @@DATEFIRST setting of sql server and would only match to Thursday if @@DATEFIRST is 7

Comment: I mention it in my answer. And with a change depending on the setting can give the right result.

Comment: got it, just specifying @@DATEFIRST to make the place to set the "first day of the week" obvious to a less initiated individual if they happen upon your answer.  I think it is a creative and decent answer I just don't like the dependence on @@DATEFIRST from a personal perspective.

Comment: This works well although I believe it should use "12-...." rather than "13-...".  Thank you.

Comment: I tested it as I mention in my answer, for the setting Sunday as first day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

Try identifying number of day in week with `DATEPART` and then adding enough days to go to next thursday:

```
declare @dt date = '2019-03-22'
declare @weekDay int

SELECT @weekDay =  DATEPART(dw, @dt)  

if @weekDay <= 5 
    select DATEADD(day, 5 - @weekDay ,@dt)
else
    select DATEADD(day,  12 - @weekDay  ,@dt)
```

Comment: This answer is also dependent upon the @@DATEFIRST setting in sql server