# Postgres - Get the monday of week X

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime, dayofweek

In Postgres, given week X in year Y, how to get the Monday date of that week/year?

Example:

```
monday_of(1, 2020) -> '2020-01-30'
monday_of(33, 2020) -> '2020-08-10'
monday_of(53, 2020) -> '2020-12-28'
monday_of(54, 2020) -> '' (year does not have 54 weeks)
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989762

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get this week's monday's date in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989762/get-this-weeks-mondays-date-in-postgres)

Comment: How does 1/2020 result in 2019-01-30?  I'm baffled by the logic.

Comment: @blami no, because that answer gives the monday of the "current" week, rather than an arbitrary one

Comment: @GordonLinoff, there, fixed that horrendous mistake that baffled logic for the entire mankind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use date arithmetics. Assuming that `yr` and `wk` are the year and week parameters:

```
date_trunc('week', make_date(yr, 1, 1)) + (wk- 1) * interval '1 week'
```

Note, however, that this does not detect out of range weeks (but you can easily add conditional logic to handle that).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ff6d53ed3f65f1446993049aa34e579c)**:

```
select yr, wk, date_trunc('week', make_date(yr, 1, 1)) + (wk- 1) * interval '1 week' res
from (values (1, 2020), (33, 2020), (53, 2020), (54, 2020)) as t(wk, yr)
```

```
  yr | wk | res                   
---: | -: | :---------------------
2020 |  1 | 2019-12-30 00:00:00+00
2020 | 33 | 2020-08-10 00:00:00+01
2020 | 53 | 2020-12-28 00:00:00+00
2020 | 54 | 2021-01-04 00:00:00+00
```

Comment: I would probably write `(yr || '-01-01')::date` as `make_date(yr,1,1)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: indeed that's cleaner... Thank you.