# select values of a specific month from table contain timestamp column

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

For example I have a following table(tbl_trans) like below

```
transaction_id  transaction_dte
integer         timestamp without time zone
---------------+----------------------------------
45             |  2014-07-17 00:00:00
56             |  2014-07-17 00:00:00
78             |  2014-04-17 00:00:00
```

so how can I find the tottal no.of transaction in  7th month from tbl_trans ?

so the expected output is

```
tot_tran  month
--------+-------
2         | July
```

Comment: with date part or extract, I'll give you a proper answer in a minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select count(transaction_id) tot_tran
      ,to_char(max(transaction_dte),'Month') month from tbl_trans
where extract (month from transaction_dte)=7
```

PostgreSQL Extract function explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29839100/3682599)

Reference : [Date/Time Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(transaction_id),date_part('month',transaction_dte)
from tbli_trans where date_part('month',transaction_dte)=7
```

Answer (score -1):

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP transaction_dte)
```

OR

```
date_part('month', timestamp transaction_dte)
```

You only need to add the word timestamp if your timestamp is saved in a string format

Properly looked up what the difference between the 2 is now:

> The extract function is primarily intended for computational
>   processing. For formatting date/time values for display.
>
> The date_part function is modeled on the traditional Ingres equivalent
>   to the SQL-standard function extract.

Comment: I need to stop hitting the post button without thinking properly about what I am typing :p

Answer (score -2):

Use Datepart function.

```
where datepart(transaction_dte, mm) = 7
```