# How to use date format in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT distinct to_char(order_date, 'Mon') as mon from meta.ship_error order 
by to_char(order_date, 'Mon') asc
```

and the output is:

```
 "Apr" 
 "Aug" 
 "Dec" 
 "Feb" 
 "Jan" 
 "Jun" 
 "Mar" 
 "May" 
 "Nov" 
 "Oct" 
 "Sep" 
  ""
```

but I want output like:

```
 jan
 feb
 mar
 apr  ....
```

What changes should I do In my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are ordering by the textual representation of the month, here:

```
order by to_char(order_date, 'Mon') asc
```

The result of `to_char` is  a string, so the ordering is alphabetical; Postgres no longer knows this has anything to do with dates, so has no reason to put "jan" before "apr".

You want to order by either the date itself:

```
order by order_date asc
```

Or by a numeric representation of the month, which you could get using [`extract()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

```
order by extract(month from order_date) asc
```

Note that since your `DISTINCT` is currently grouping based on the textual representation, you may have trouble making the `SELECT` and `ORDER BY` use different representations. This will be easier with an explicit `GROUP BY`, which can list both representations:

```
group by extract(month from order_date), to_char(order_date, 'Mon')
```

Since you can be sure that a given `order_date` can't produce a separate value for those two columns, this won't change the number of rows, but allows you to write this:

```
select to_char(order_date, 'Mon')
from meta.ship_error
group by extract(month from order_date), to_char(order_date, 'Mon')
order by extract(month from order_date);
```

Comment: but i need output in JAN , FEB ...  and by using extract(month from order_date) it gives 1 ,2 ,3 ...

Comment: @Shubhambatra I didn't say to change the `SELECT`, only the `ORDER BY`. That said, you will have problems because of the `DISTINCT`. I'll edit in an extra change.

Answer (score 0):

using this query i got my solution

```
SELECT distinct to_char(order_date, 'Mon') as MON , extract(month from 

order_date) from meta.ship_error order by extract(month from order_date) asc
```

Comment: this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29839100/3682599) may useful for you in future