# hour from timestamp in postgresql for dynamic queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named `employee` with 5 columns. One column is named `emp_empdt` it's type is `timestamp` .

I need to get hour value of `emp_empdt` of every record in the `employee` table.

I know that, we can get hour by using like

```
SELECT extract(hour from timestamp '2015-05-02 20:05:12');
```

This is an static `query`. 
But now i need to get `timestamp` value from `employee` table.

I used like:

```
SELECT h1 
from (
   select extract(hour from timestamp emp.emp_empdt) as h1 
   from employee emp
);
```

Comment: for more extract function ->http://stackoverflow.com/a/29839100/3682599

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `timestamp` keyword is not required:

```
select extract(hour from emp_empdt) as h1 
from employee emp
```

The expression `timestamp '2015-05-02 20:05:12'` is an ANSI SQL timestamp literal and the keyword `timestamp` is only required for a literal like that. This is necessary to distinguish such an expression from a  *character* literal (`'2015-05-02 20:05:12'`).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name :  Not working while executing above query its say : HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.