# Year, Next Year, Quarter e Next Quarter based in a FISCAL YEAR

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to bring the results of this SQL showing all the data of "MY FISCAL YEAR" that started in 1st june, and other SQL to showing all the data of the "NEXT FISCAL YEAR", because I made it based on the database calendar.

btw, the last fiscal year ended in 31 MAY

The user will sent the request with the sysdate by an API request. For example, if a user sent a request in october 2022 the result of my SQL need to be all projects of my fiscal year (2022-2023) as I said that started 1st june.

My SQL is returning all projects in 2022 based on the database calendar

```
select
 dgl.LABEL                as goLiveName  
,dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_ACTUAL   as planningCurrent
,dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED  as planningBaseline
,dgl.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE as effectiveStartDate
,dgl.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE   as effectiveEndDate
from   DATALAKE.DWL_GOLIVE dgl
      ,DATALAKE.DWB_PROJECT dp
where dgl.PROJECT_ID = dp.PROJECT_ID
and   to_char(dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED, 'YYYY') = to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') 
AND   ( :year = 'true')
```

[image: YEAR 2022]

This is my SQL that showing all projects in 2023 based on the database calendar, but as I said, in this SQL, I need all the projects of my Next Fiscal Year 2023-2024

```
select
 dgl.LABEL                as goLiveName  
,dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_ACTUAL   as planningCurrent
,dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED  as planningBaseline
,dgl.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE as effectiveStartDate
,dgl.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE   as effectiveEndDate
from   DATALAKE.DWL_GOLIVE dgl
      ,DATALAKE.DWB_PROJECT dp
where dgl.PROJECT_ID = dp.PROJECT_ID
and   to_char(dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED, 'YYYY') = to_char (add_months (SYSDATE, 12), 'YYYY' )
AND   ( :nyear = 'true')
```

[image: NEXT YEAR 2023]

In the same way, I will need the ACTUAL QUARTER and the NEXT QUARTER based on my FISCAL YEAR that I mentioned. because I did it based on the database quarter. and the database quarter now is Q2. But in my calendar fiscal year need to be Q1 to show the result from June.

```
select
 dgl.LABEL                as goLiveName  
,dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_ACTUAL   as planningCurrent
,dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED  as planningBaseline
,dgl.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE as effectiveStartDate
,dgl.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE   as effectiveEndDate
from   DATALAKE.DWL_GOLIVE dgl
      ,DATALAKE.DWB_PROJECT dp
where dgl.PROJECT_ID = dp.PROJECT_ID
and   to_char(dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED, 'yyyy-q') = to_char(SYSDATE, 'yyyy-q')
AND   ( :quarter = 'true')
```

[image: QUARTER BASED ON THE DATABASE CALENDAR]

The next quarter base on the data base calendar

```
select
 dgl.LABEL                as goLiveName  
,dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_ACTUAL   as planningCurrent
,dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED  as planningBaseline
,dgl.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE as effectiveStartDate
,dgl.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE   as effectiveEndDate
from   DATALAKE.DWL_GOLIVE dgl
      ,DATALAKE.DWB_PROJECT dp
where dgl.PROJECT_ID = dp.PROJECT_ID
and   dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'Q'), 3)
and   dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED <  add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'Q'), 6)
--and   to_char (dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED, 'yyyy - q' ) >= to_char (add_months (to_date('12/08/22', 'dd/mm/yy'), 3), 'yyyy - q' ) -- EXEMPLO
--and   to_char (dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED, 'yyyy - q' ) < to_char (add_months (to_date('12/08/22', 'dd/mm/yy'), 6), 'yyyy - q' )
AND   ( :nquarter = 'true')
```

[image: THE NEXT QUARTER BASED ON THE DATABASE CALENDAR]

Please guys, anyone can help me ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you consider using a [calendar table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5030686/562459)?

Comment: A solid way to achieve this is to create a DATE dimension table. 1 record per date and columns: date, week, qtr, year, fiscal week, fiscal quarter, fiscal year. Populate that table and join to it to: group by a certain period, query on a period etc. Yould also add prev_fiscal_qtr etc.
This removes the need of having to calculate the fiscal periods in every single query.

Comment: hmmmmm, I was considering doing it this way, it seems to me to be the smartest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fiscal year (2022-06-01 - 2023-05-30):

```sql
SELECT dgl.LABEL                as goLiveName  
      ,dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_ACTUAL   as planningCurrent
      ,dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED  as planningBaseline
      ,dgl.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE as effectiveStartDate
      ,dgl.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE   as effectiveEndDate
      ,TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED, -5), 'YYYY') AS fiscalyear
FROM   DATALAKE.DWL_GOLIVE dgl
       INNER JOIN DATALAKE.DWB_PROJECT dp
       ON (dgl.PROJECT_ID = dp.PROJECT_ID)
WHERE  dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED
         >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -5), 'YY'),  5)
AND    dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED
         <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -5), 'YY'), 17)
AND    ( :year = 'true')
```

Next fiscal year (2023-06-01 - 2024-05-30):

```sql
SELECT dgl.LABEL                as goLiveName  
      ,dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_ACTUAL   as planningCurrent
      ,dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED  as planningBaseline
      ,dgl.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE as effectiveStartDate
      ,dgl.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE   as effectiveEndDate
      ,TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED, -5), 'YYYY') AS fiscalyear
FROM   DATALAKE.DWL_GOLIVE dgl
       INNER JOIN DATALAKE.DWB_PROJECT dp
       ON (dgl.PROJECT_ID = dp.PROJECT_ID)
WHERE  dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED
         >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -5), 'YY'), 17)
AND    dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED
         <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -5), 'YY'), 29)
AND    ( :nyear = 'true')
```

Current quarter (2022-06-01 - 2022-08-31 - 2022Q1):

```sql
SELECT dgl.LABEL                as goLiveName  
      ,dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_ACTUAL   as planningCurrent
      ,dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED  as planningBaseline
      ,dgl.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE as effectiveStartDate
      ,dgl.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE   as effectiveEndDate
      ,TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED, -5), 'YYYY-Q') AS quarter
FROM   DATALAKE.DWL_GOLIVE dgl
       INNER JOIN DATALAKE.DWB_PROJECT dp
       ON (dgl.PROJECT_ID = dp.PROJECT_ID)
WHERE  dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED
         >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2), 'Q'), 2)
AND    dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED
         <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2), 'Q'), 5)
AND    ( :quarter = 'true')
```

Next quarter (2022-09-01 - 2022-11-30 - 2022Q2):

```sql
SELECT dgl.LABEL                as goLiveName  
      ,dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_ACTUAL   as planningCurrent
      ,dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED  as planningBaseline
      ,dgl.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE as effectiveStartDate
      ,dgl.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE   as effectiveEndDate
      ,TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED, -5), 'YYYY-Q') AS quarter
FROM   DATALAKE.DWL_GOLIVE dgl
       INNER JOIN DATALAKE.DWB_PROJECT dp
       ON (dgl.PROJECT_ID = dp.PROJECT_ID)
WHERE  dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED
         >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2), 'Q'), 5)
AND    dgl.GOLIVE_DATE_PLANNED
         <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2), 'Q'), 8)
AND    ( :nquarter = 'true')
```